# Table Design for Invoice

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I'm developing an software in vb.net with accessdb for a small business. In this I had to make an invoice I have product table, client table I have to make an invoice / order / transaction now. I'm confused in items like custem A buy 10 items on diffrent quantaty and diffrente rate how should I store those 10 items it can be 5 or 15 or more than that how shoul I store it. what will be the best way to do this. I was thinkning to make a new row for each items but it will be waste of storage. is there any smart way to do this.

Comment: Searching for `database normalization` will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the data normalized.

the bridge table Order_product has a m:n relation ship.

you can extend the schema, by adding a city table country table and so on so that you save only integers instead of city names

```
Customer   product     order     Order_Product
c_id       p_id        o_id      o_id
c_name     p_name      o_date    p_id
c_adress               c_id      qty
c_city                           rate
```

Joining all tables by their foreign keys you can easily get all nformation yu want

Comment: Understood but in the scenario where shoul I store basic amount(which is total amount of all products) freight rate, delivery rate, total amount(which is basic amount + freight rate + delivery rate), advanced recived and pending amount ??? in order table or i have to calculate every time when user calls for the invoice ??

Comment: the columns belong all in the order table(also normalized) you need to decide where it is best positioned in one of the table, the total can be calculated by tzhe quatity the weight also, so you don't save calculated values, the rest is as you which but most of the values mentioned belong to order